# ngx_http_geoip_module module version is wrong after updating nginx on CentOS and nginx won't start

Tags: nginx, centos

I would very much like to update my nginx but every time I do, it just breaks and when restarted/started it gives me an error. Status is this:

```
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-05-02 07:11:10 UTC; 2min 0s ago
Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
Process: 1055 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 774 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 02 07:11:10 mixt4vps systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
May 02 07:11:10 mixt4vps nginx[1055]: nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" version 1012002 instead of 1014000 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1
May 02 07:11:10 mixt4vps systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 02 07:11:10 mixt4vps systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
May 02 07:11:10 mixt4vps systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
May 02 07:11:10 mixt4vps systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Do you guys have any idea what i can do? I keep restoring snapshots but everytime I try to update again it happens again.

Comment: Looks like Nginx has documentation for that issue: https://www.nginx.com/blog/failed-nginx-plus-upgrade-module-version-x-instead-of-y/

Comment: I found that too but it is about "Recovering from a Failed NGINX Plus Upgrade" but I'm using nginx so their guide isn't applicable

Comment: In this aspect nginx and nginx plus are the same, so the recovery will be the same. Compiling nginx however is a bit of overkill for such an error, is that the nginx from EPEL or other repo? You can probably use the RPMs from the nginx repo - http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

Answer (score 0):

Disable temporarily your nginx service : `sudo systemctl disable nginx` on Debian.
Then upgrade you packages.
If needed install the missing modules : e.g. :

`sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-passenger libnginx-mod-http-geoip libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream-geoip`

Once everything is installed, enable back your nginx service and start it :

`sudo systemctl enable nginx; systemctl start nginx`